# Image in/visible after dropdown choice

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

When I select a language in the dropdown menu the matching language image should appear in a `div` next to it, making the irrelevant images invisible. I can't get it to work, I've been trying with `display: none;` and `block;` and with `.hide()` `.show()`

Can someone see what I am doing wrong here?

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
  <div id="navLanguage">
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlLanguages" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" >
    <asp:ListItem Text="English" Value="en-us" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="Nederlands" Value="nl" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="Português" Value="pt-br" />
    </asp:DropDownList>
  </div>
</form>

<div ID="Flags" runat="server">
    <asp:Image runat="server" ID="FlagUK" imageUrl="Images/Language Icons/FlagUK.png" Value="en-us" />
    <asp:Image runat="server" ID="FlagNL" imageUrl="Images/Language Icons/FlagNL.png" Value="nl" />
    <asp:Image runat="server" ID="FlagBR" imageUrl="Images/Language Icons/FlagBR.png" Value="pt-br" />
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#ddlLanguages').on ('change', function () {
      var selected = $(this).val();
      if (selected === "en-us") {
        $('#FlagUK').show();
        $('#FlagNL').hide();
        $('#FlagBR').hide();
      }
      if (selected === "nl") {
        $('#FlagUK').hide();
        $('#FlagNL').show();
        $('#FlagBR').hide();
      }
      if (selected === "pt-br") {
        $('#FlagUK').hide();
        $('#FlagNL').hide();
        $('#FlagBR').show();
      }
    });
 });
</script>
```

Comment: It looks like you're using ASP.Net webforms. As such all the `ID` attributes or your `runat="server"` controls will be changed dynamically at runtime. If you inspect the DOM in the browser you will see they are completely different to what your code expects them to be. To fix this use the `ClientID` property of the control to access it, or use classes.

Comment: Also note that jQuery 1.3.2 is positively ancient. You *really* need to upgrade it to at least 1.12.1, ideally 3.3.1

Comment: You have autopostback=true, so if the page is posting when you make a selection, then your JS will never execute.

Comment: Ok... and what could be a practical solution for this code?

Comment: @Rory McCrossan: I am using ASP.NET with MVS. This code i wrote is placed on the masterpage, isn't it true that using a ClientID property is unnecessary for a masterpage? Also when I check the DOM the ID attribute matches with the code

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try change the 'change' event to 'click' event
in this way you select the dom directly and have the value from it.

Comment: The click event seems to work, but only while clicking. What do I need to use if I want to keep the value also after clicking?

Comment: you can save the value in cache, cookies